# Maps not showing up in API Level 9 to 17 using Fragment

Tags: android, google-maps, google-play-services

i have work around with many tutorials , done everything but not showed up with maps i always end up with a Zoom control view of a map,
i think there is a problem with manifest

My Code is as given below

Manifest:

```
 <application android:icon="@drawable/logo" android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity android:name=".Main" android:noHistory="true"
                  android:label="@string/app_name" >

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY" android:value="my api key"/>

    <activity android:name="Activity2" android:label="@string/app_name" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" />   


    </application>

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="9"   android:targetSdkVersion="10" />


    <uses-feature  android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"    android:required="true"/>   

    <uses-permission android:name="my_package_name.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CLEAR_APP_USER_DATA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CLEAR_APP_CACHE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_LOGS" />
```

My mapview.xml is

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <fragment
        xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

My Main Activity Class

```
public class Main extends FragmentActivity  {

      private String sResponse;
      static final LatLng HAMBURG = new LatLng(53.558, 9.927);
      static final LatLng KIEL = new LatLng(53.551, 9.993);
      private GoogleMap map;

    @Override
      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        try{
        setContentView(R.layout.mapview);

        GoogleMap map = ((SupportMapFragment)  getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-33.867, 151.206);

        map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(sydney, 13));

        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .title("Sydney")
                .snippet("The most populous city in Australia.")
                .position(sydney));
        }
        catch(Exception ex){

        }
     }
```

i dont know what is wrong , i have also imported the support library  google-play-service_lib into project from  SDK
Could anybody please tell where m i  going wrong
Thanks in advance !

**EDIT**

When i add this permission in manifest

```
<permission
        android:name="my_package_name.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />
```

it gives me Error

```
Installation error: INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED
Please check logcat output for more details.
Launch canceled!
```

Any Help..?

Comment: Which API key are you using? Did you use your debug or release certificate to create the key? In which way are you generating the apk from your IDE? Debug or Release?

Comment: i am generating it in Debug Key with the package name :)

Comment: Could you please post the logcat your get in case of error INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED? Thanks.

Comment: Also, we don't have your package name, but do you have any capital letter in it? If so, please try using all low cases letters.

Comment: @fasteque yes it do have capital name in package so should i use all small letters

Comment: Yes, use all small letters and of course set that permisison "my_package_name.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" to use maps.

Comment: @fasteque i have created an api which is allowed on any device which worked for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY" 
android:value="my api key"/>
```

replace the "my api key"  with your api key like this

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY" 
   android:value="AIzaSyAS-3h00tgAf9nSCrwgI02DZ9zMyaIhQQY"/>
```

get api key from here https://code.google.com/apis/console/

For step by step tutorial go here : [Map Tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/08/android-working-with-google-maps-v2/)

Comment: i already have api key i have mentiomed that "my api key" this is not the issue

Comment: G  i have my api key and i have put here  any further suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Check your manifest, as you mentioned target as 10, increase targetSDK version like this

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8"   
 android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
```